# Erro ao inserir dados no banco de dados

Tags: php, sql

Estou acompanhando aulas de `php`, e no vídeo o cara usa o comando `mysql`, mas sei que ele é velho e inseguro e usei o `mysqli`, porém o código não apresenta erro, mas não grava dados na minha tabela, segue a página do formulário e do `INSERT` :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Comentário</title>
</head>


<body>
    <form method="post" action="#">
        <table>  
        <tr>
             <td><h1>Comente</h1></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nome</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="txtNome"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td><input type="email" name="txtEmail"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mensagem</td>
            <td><textarea name="txtMsg"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td><?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Comentar"/></td>
            <td><input type="reset" value="Cancelar"/></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['txtNome']))
        $nome = $_POST['txtNome'];
    else
        $nome = '';
    if(isset($_POST['txtEmail']))
        $email = $_POST['txtEmail'];
    else
        $email = '';
    if(isset($_POST['txtMsg']))
        $msg = $_POST['txtMsg'];
    else
        $msg = '';
    $data = date("Y-m-d");
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'aula', '3306');
    if (!$conn) {
        die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    mysqli_query($conn, 'SET NAMES \'utf8\'');
    $tableQuery = "INSERT INTO `comentario`(`id`, `nome`, `email`, `msg`, `data`) VALUES ('','$nome','$email','$msg','$data')";
    mysqli_query($conn, $tableQuery);
    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>

</body>


</html>
```

E o script do bd:

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
--
-- Database: `aula`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `comentario`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comentario` (
  `id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(80) DEFAULT 'nome',
  `email` varchar(80) DEFAULT 'main@main.com',
  `msg` varchar(1000) DEFAULT 'mensagem',
  `data` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Qual seria o meu erro?

Comment: Coloca o musqli_error($conexão)

Comment: Só apareceu `Duplicata du champ '' pour la clef 'PRIMARY'`

Comment: O erro diz que o código inserido já existe, só isso. A coluna `id` deveria int, not null e autoincrement.

Comment: Eu recriei a tabela e funcionou, somente o id que não incrementa, esqueci do autoincrement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O erro diz que o código inserido já existe, isso acontece porque a coluna `id` é um varchar e a sua unicidade nesse caso depende do sistema/aplicação. Para deixar essa responsabilidade com o banco de dados, mude essa coluna para `int`, not null e `auto increment`

```
`id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

Answer (score 2):

O erro era no script da tabela, agora ficou assim:

```
--
-- Database: `aula`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `comentario`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comentario` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `msg` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```